# I need to setting author when saving model's instance

Tags: django, django-models

This is my model:

```
class News(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  text = models.TextField()
  pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
  author = models.ForeignKey(User)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

And I have a simple form for it:

```
class NewsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = News
            exclude = ('pub_date','author',)
```

I'm excluding pub_date because it's settings by default, and author because it will be current user.
But how set author to current logged user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend overwriting the `save()` method and passing the user to it like this:

```
class NewsForm(ModelForm):

    def save(self, author, commit=True):
        # Don't commit the results yet
        news = ModelForm.save(self, commit=False)
        news.author = author
        if commit:
            news.save()
        return news

    class Meta:
            model = News
            exclude = ('pub_date','author',)
```